# C# - MySQL Prevent TINYINT(1) to Boolean Conversion

Tags: c#, mysql, byte, tinyint

Is there any way to prevent the conversion from TINYINT(1) to boolean? Or perhaps convert it to int instead?

My TINYINT(1) column can have data such as 0, 1, 2, 3. But it is being converted to False, True, True, True respectively.

Here is the code that I currently use:

```
using (Cmd = new MySqlCommand())
{
    Cmd.Connection = Conn;
    SetQuery();

    using (var dt = new DataTable())
    {
        dt.Load(Cmd.ExecuteReader());
        ObjectList = dt.AsEnumerable().ToArray();=
    }

    Parse();

    return ObjectList != null;
}
```

Hope you can help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is TINYINT?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, he means one of the table column is `TINYINT(1)`

Comment: I don't know, but as I read posts it seems they are kinda same. if tinyint is just 1 byte you maybe able to retrieve that using unsafe code? take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4980975/4767498

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve an int value rather than a boolean from a TINYINT(1) column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728994/how-to-retrieve-an-int-value-rather-than-a-boolean-from-a-tinyint1-column)

Answer (score 1):

`TINYINT` is basically 1 `byte` in SQL Server, and its .Net  equivalent is `byte`. 
You can do this in multiple ways, have a look.

```
int x = (int)(byte) reader["column"];
int x = (byte) reader["column"];
int x = reader.GetByte(column);
```

Refere [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx)

Comment: This question asks about MySQL, not SQL Server.

Comment: I know but the basic concepts are same in both

Answer (score 0):

Though your posted code nowhere shows the actual conversion  from `TINYINT(1)` to `boolean` as you mentioned but you can try casting it to `byte` like

```
(byte)rdr["columnwithtinyintdatatype"];
```