# Get numeric value from boolean

Tags: c#, .net

I prefer casting boolean value to integer, but I found using conditional operator ?: like in example:

```
boolVal ? 1 : 0;
```

I think it looks ridiculous. What is most efficient way to get numeric value from boolean value in .NET?

Comment: You only care about efficiency?

Comment: Why do you need the integer value instead of `true` or `false`?

Comment: bool f = true;
int y = Convert.ToInt32(f);

Comment: @pix read the first line, he knows how to cast its about speed

Comment: It's why it's only a comment and not an answer :)

Comment: I'm aware of at least 5 ways to achieve same results. Also I'm aware that conditional operator ?: is sort of shorthand for if-else statement. I'm curious about *the best* solution and which more people prefer. That one quoted by me looks pretty bad.

Comment: Someone already ask how to convert bool to byte, maybe you can inspire yourself with this "tricks" to do it on integer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980881/what-is-fastest-way-to-convert-bool-to-byte

Comment: Both ternary operator & `Convert.ToInt32` are correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457366/c-sharp-boolean-int-conversion-issue (as alternatives: `if`, `switch` or any conditional statements). Seems it just a kind of casting readability instead performance.

Comment: @Bear So it's not only about speed?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom It is, but readability also matters. Of course it's pretty easy to understand what happened there, but I mean code should be nice and most efficient. Purists versus Pragmatists...

Comment: @MightyBadaboom To me it seems more an aesthetic issue at hand, and he is asking what the "majority" of C# developer uses - no matter what solution they will most likely differ in nanoseconds (if even that)

Comment: This question is off topic here since there is no single right answer. I believe the ternary operator is "the most efficient" (or at least one of the ...), but either way "what people prefer" is opinion-based, so off topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is fastest way to convert bool to byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980881/what-is-fastest-way-to-convert-bool-to-byte)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cew9dz7(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int zeroOrOne = Convert.ToInt32(boolVal);
```

Use the most readable approach, performance will be the same.

This is the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,d75d8ee9b3529289,references) of `Convert.ToInt32`:

```
public static int ToInt32(bool value) {
    return value? Boolean.True: Boolean.False;
}
```

Comment: @EpicKip: you cannot cast a bool to int. What you could do is to cast it to `IConvertible` and then use `ToInt32` which is the same as above because it will call `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: At the `return` it still uses ternary operator; same as OP has. Someone already found that both ternary & `Convert.ToInt32` follows same instructions: https://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-bool-int.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto: i have posted the .net code in my answer, you can see that it internally uses the conditional operator

Comment: The updated source code, seemed odd at first sight - since I believed that ``Boolean.True`` is a ``bool`` and not an ``int``, naming is kinda missleading. TIL Microsoft guys are just as bad with naming stuff as I am. :)

Comment: @RandRandom: [`Boolean.True`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/boolean.cs,440a570fbff23b16,references) is an int. Well, it's `internal`

Comment: ? Thanks for telling, but thats what I said... ``since I believed that Boolean.True is a bool and not an int`` - I ``believed`` it was a ``bool`` at first sight - I already know its an int, whats why I said ``naming is kinda missleading``

Answer (score 1):

I ran a quick test and comparing the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) and [Convert.ToInt32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cew9dz7(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
bool bVal = true;
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();
for(int i =0; i < amountOfTries; i++ )
{
    int b = bVal ? 1 : 0;
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine( $"Conditional operator: {sw.ElapsedTicks}t" );

sw.Restart();
for( int i = 0; i < amountOfTries; i++ )
{
    int b = Convert.ToInt32(bVal);
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine( $"Convert: {sw.ElapsedTicks}t" );
```

Result with `1000000` (1 million) tries:

Conditional operator: 7518 ticks
Convert: 8744 ticks

So the conditional operator is slightly faster in this case (its such a small difference the result can be different too). I think the Convert looks clearer personally though.

**Note:**  As you can see in [Tim Schmelter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45813351/2885376), under the hood `Convert.ToInt32(bool)` does practically the same as the conditional operator.

Comment: It's really negligible. I have created a [`BenchMarkDotNet`](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) test which showed other results: `ConditonalOperator=299.3722 us` and  `ToInt32=290.2959 us`, so `ToInt32` is even slightly faster. You have to compile in release mode and run without attached debugger

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's why I added the footnote :), I couldn't repro ToInt32 being faster but I could remote the line that says its faster because it'd be false if you get different results

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: For those of us not familiar with such fine grained performance measurements does 299.3722 us = one third of one millisecond?

Comment: @camelCase: it's microsecond(0.000001 sec), read [here](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/issues/459). Btw, my test also iterates 1million times

Comment: @EpicKip, note that your test is somehow misleading, since you use always the same value (true) and that matters (look for "branch prediction" to understand why). With random values results are much slower, but, as expected, Convert and Conditional have similar timing. See it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DkikU2)