# Branchless min/max methods in c#

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, max, min

I've recently learned about branchless programming. I found example of branchless min method. In pesudocode it's something like this

```
function Max(a, b)
{
    return a * (a > b) + b * (a <= b);
}
```

This code works only under condition that in used language true can be casted to 1 and false to 0. In c# however it doesn't seem to work, since true and false aren't just aliases for 1 and 0, but actual logical values. Can min and max methods be implemented branchless in any other way in C#?

Comment: return a * ((a > b)? 1 : 0) + b * ((a <= b)? 1 : 0);

Comment: `Math.Max` and `Math.Min`

Comment: But isn't "?" operator just masked if? If it is, then it's not branchless. And as far as I'm concern, Math.Max implementation is just if statement.

Comment: `return a * Convert.ToInt32(a > b) + b * Convert.ToInt32(a <= b);` has no explicit branches; however, `Convert.ToInt32` can well have `if`s

Comment: @DmitryBychenko but `Convert.ToInt32` [has](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Convert.cs,d75d8ee9b3529289)

Comment: @PrzemekNowaczyk maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58934996/c-sharp-reinterpret-bool-as-byte-int-branch-free) will help?

Comment: Is `using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86` allowed? You can use that to write code that is for sure branchless

Comment: I think your Min pseudocode is actually Max.

Answer (score 5):

Just an FYI for anyone thinking of implementing some "speedhack" like this... The runtime and compiler are obviously already aware of optimizations like this and have already applied them for you. You don't need to reinvent the wheel. Quick benchmarks show only miniscule differences between the "fast" branchless method, naive `x > y ? x : y`, and `Math.Max()`.

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=Windows 10.0.22000
AMD Ryzen 7 3800X, 1 CPU, 16 logical and 8 physical cores
.NET SDK=6.0.300
  [Host]     : .NET 6.0.5 (6.0.522.21309), X64 RyuJIT
  Job-RVHKGU : .NET 6.0.5 (6.0.522.21309), X64 RyuJIT
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SimpleTernaryMax | 96.41 ms | 1.126 ms | 3.025 ms | 95.21 ms | 480 B |
| BranchlessMax | 98.34 ms | 1.428 ms | 3.884 ms | 97.23 ms | 480 B |
| BuiltInMathMax | 97.14 ms | 0.860 ms | 2.280 ms | 96.60 ms | 768 B |

Comment: Did your benchmark saturate the branch predictor? I ask because my understanding with branchless code is that it proves its worth when run within a hot loop which has other branches. Keeping the number of branches as low as possible will increase the chance that the branch predictor can operate at full speed, IIRC.

Comment: Additionally, the following basic conditional method JITs to `asm` containing a `jne` in .NET 6: `static T If<T>(bool condition, T then, T @else) => condition ? then : @else;` https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIAYACY8gOgCUBXAOwwEt8YLAMIR8AB14AbGFADKMgG68wMXAG4a9BrIAW2KGIAy2YO258BG6jQDaAKV4YA4jC4zlACgwBPMTAgAZh68PACUoQC6muRIDAAqDACSAQA8cQB8HsAQEJIMkFwAJo68EFxo8QwYOq4VCcTEMJK4MKE0AN40AJDEAOz5ZcV8ZQwA/FU1XAwgTI3NMFYAvjS2Ds6u7mBevv5BIRjhUbQxlcmkaZnZuQNFJWV1E7WVDU0tbdSd1D39AKpcuNgAoIAIKFQoeWABWavGAVP4AoEsYG4FIAIRy0mw5QYqO8GBgmUhNyGpS44SWQA

Answer (score 2):

Using @GuruStron's hint, here is an extension method:

```
public static class BoolExt {
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct TBoolInt32 {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public bool Bool;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int Int;
    }

    public static int ToInt32(this bool value) => Unsafe.As<bool, TBoolInt32>(ref value).Int;
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
public int Min(int a, int b) => a * (a < b).ToInt32() + b * (a >= b).ToInt32();
```

However, even with `AgressiveInlining` in IL this causes two calls to `ToInt32` so isn't really more efficient.

Another possibility is to use the implementation of `Math.Sign` (not sure if it inlines so I reimplemented) to create tests that return 0 or 1:

```
public static class TestExt {
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    static int IntSign(int value) => (value >> 31) | (int)((uint)(-value) >> 31);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static int GreaterEqual(this int a, int b) => IntSign(IntSign(a - b) + 1);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static int LessThan(this int a, int b) => 1 - a.GreaterEqual(b);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static int LesserEqual(this int a, int b) => IntSign(IntSign(b - a) + 1);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static int GreaterThan(this int a, int b) => 1 - a.LesserEqual(b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use bitwise and shift operators like this:

```
int FastMax(int a, int b) {
  int diff = a - b;
  int dsgn = diff >> 31;
  return a - (diff & dsgn);
}
```

The `>>` operator is right shift and I use 31 for `Int` you can use 63 for `long` numbers.

FYI: see this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach. It requires some unsafe code to cast the `bool` to a `byte` (0 or 1) which we use as an offset to choose which argument to return.

```cs
static int Min(int a, int b) => If(a < b, a, b);

static int Max(int a, int b) => If(a < b, b, a);

static T If<T>(bool condition, T then, T @else)
{
    return Unsafe.Add(ref @else, Unsafe.As<bool, byte>(ref condition));
}
```

You can see that it doesn't produce any branching instructions: [SharpLab link](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIAYACY8gOgCUBXAOwwEt8YLAMIR8AB14AbGFADKMgG68wMXAG4a9BrIAW2KGIAy2YO258BG6pvJIGvHgwCyDgBQOMDbGnuPgASgYAXgA+BgBJADNXbAYAHgZgH29E/ysbOw9nbAR3RxSsgOCwqJj4xJ8krzSaGgBtACleDABxGC4ZZVcMAE8xGAhoj39/AF0MhgAVCMi4yZDXYAgISQZILgATZt4ILh9pjB12/aZiGElcGH8aAG8aAEhiAHYGAFUuXGxIwQBBDY3XLBIqdzpcfO9Pt8WD9cHElitKj0MDAFkC1rstnxdiMrABfWq0Wy+TwuLikPKeAp+QKhGbk2IJKopALpQmZRxOHLkrJUzxFWlRenlKpMmrWaiNZptDpQLq9fqDCkjcZsqZ0uYLeGrdaYnZ7NWHY5q4hnC5XW4PZ7ozbbXYMAD8DENXAYIBBZrxQA===).

If you're using the upcoming .NET 7, you can make `Min` and `Max` generic like this:

```cs
static T Min<T>(T a, T b) where T : IComparisonOperators<T, T, bool> =>
    If(a < b, a, b);

static T Max<T>(T a, T b) where T : IComparisonOperators<T, T, bool> =>
    If(a < b, b, a);
```